# Changing the color of navigationController's backButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to change the color of backButton of navigation controller using gradient.
I have changed the color of navigatonBar but unable to change color of backButton.
If I use `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor` 
the color of both bar and backButton is changed but i want to aplly a gradient as i did for navigationBar

```
CGRect navFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
navFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer insertSublayer:[AddGradient addGradientToNavigationBar:navFrame] atIndex:0];
```

the code for addGradientToNavigationBar is

```
+ (CAGradientLayer*)addGradientToNavigationBar:(CGRect)navRect {

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = navRect;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0] CGColor],
                       (id)[[XAppDelegate getColor] CGColor], nil];
    return gradient;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the color of your bar and button doesn't have to should dynamically, I think the best way is to use the iOS 5 [UIAppearance protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance).
Create a scalable image (i.e. with a portion that can be repeated by iOS as often as needed) and do something like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"BarGradient.png"]
                                   forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackgroundImage: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"BarButtonScalableGradient.png"]
                     resizableImageWithCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 6, 15, 6)]
                                        forState: UIControlStateNormal
                                      barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Implement this line of code:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Replace redColor with the following to adjust the color of the buttons:

```
colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:144/255.0 blue:200/255.0 alpha:1.0// pick your color using this
```

Be sure to put this in the view controller that pushes. Not the view controller where you want to see this back button color.